# How to use Yelp API v2 C# example in Umbraco site

Tags: c#, umbraco7, yelp

I'm new to .net and Umbraco in general. I have a basic site setup and want to use the Yelp API to display some content on the site. I've played with the code sample from git:

https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-api/tree/master/v2/csharp

And have successfully built that, which produces an executable command line program. My question is, how do I convert the code from the sample for use directly on the website, specifically Umbraco v7?

Any help much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should not differ a lot from the example combined with normal ASP.NET.

If you are in a [Partial view](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/templating/mvc/partial-views) or [Template](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/Templating/Mvc/views) in Umbraco your Razor code could look something like:

```
@{
  // todo: add other relevant code or link to other classes encapsulating your calls
  JObject response = client.Search(term, location);
  JArray businesses = (JArray)response.GetValue("businesses");
}

<ul>
  @foreach(var item in businesses) {
    <li>id: @item["id"]</li>
  }
</ul>
```